# Настройка SSL сертификатов Let`s Encrypt в связке с Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, ssl, dns, cloudflare, certbot

Ubuntu 20.04 + Nginx + Cloudflare

Настроен и запушен веб-сервер, сайты отдаются, но есть одна мелочь, которую так хочется решить и никак не выходит: Я получаю и настраиваю сертификаты Let`s Encrypt через Certbot по гайдам, включая поддержку wildcard-сертификатов с помощью модуля certbot-dns-cloudflare, опять же, делая всё шаг за шагом инструкции. В итоге получаю работающий сайт по https и валидный сертификат, но его сертификат отображается, как сертификат выданный для sni.cloudflaressl.com. А я хочу видеть сертификат, выданный для моего домена. Настройка SSL/TLS в Cloudflare Full(strict). Изменяя эту настройку, получаю цикличный редирект 301. При отключении перенаправления на https со стороны Cloudflare получаю небезопасный сайт с неверным сертификатом.

Как правильно настроить SSL/TLS в Cloudflare и как что я делаю не так, чтобы такая мелочь, как сертификат выданный именно для моего домена отображалась в браузере?

Comment: Или купить Etnerprise-тариф в Cloudflare и загрузить туда файлы своего сертификата, или полностью отказаться от использования Cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

1. настройте прослушивание 80 порта и location для http подтверждения. Например так:

```
    listen 80;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/certbot;
        default_type "text/plain";
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

2. настройте прослушивание порта 443 и подключите расположение сертификатов:

```
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/CERT_NAME/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/CERT_NAME/privkey.pem;
```

3. отключить редирект на https в cloudflare т.к. для подтверждения сертификата требуется доступ к серверу по протоколу http.
4. получите сертификат командой:

```
certbot certonly --cert-name CERT_NAME -d YOUR_DOMAIN --webroot --webroot-path /var/www/certbot --agree-tos
```

Comment: Это не изменит того факта, что при использовании https сертификат всё равно будет от sni.cloudflaressl.com